# O que é "Prop drilling"?

Tags: front-end, arquitetura-de-software, single-page-application

Acredito que o termo está relacionado a passar propriedades entre vários componentes, porém não entendi exatamente.

O que é o "Prop drilling"? Como evitá-lo? É uma prática comum?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**O que é o "Prop drilling"?**

Ao pé da letra, é o "vazamento de props", é quando você passa uma props, de um pai, para um filho, o filho passa para o filho dele, e assim por diante. Isso gera um "vazamento de props", por exemplo:

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    usuario: { nome: 'Gandalf'},
  };

  render() {
    const { usuario } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <PaginaUsuario
          usuario={usuario}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const PaginaUsuario = ({ usuario }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Titulo>Página do usuário</Titulo>
      <NomeUsuario usuario={usuario}/>
    </div>
  );
};

const NomeUsuario = ({ usuario }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Usuario: {usuario.nome}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

No exemplo acima, acontece o "props drilling", você passa a variável usuário para árvore toda, sendo que alguns componentes não precisam e não usam essa props, no nosso caso `PaginaUsuário`, o melhor nesse caso é se houvesse um jeito de passar variável diretamente de `Home` -> `NomeUsuario`.

**Como evitá-lo?**

Há três alternativas:

- `Redux`, mas é usado em casos específicos e quando realmente
  necessário, experiência própria, **não use** Redux se você não
  **precisa realmente**.
- `Context API` e `Render props`, o próprio React oferece ferramentas para lidar com isso.

Seguindo o caminho do `Context API`, ficaria assim o nosso exemplo acima:

```js
export const HomeContext = createContext({});

class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    usuario: { nome: 'Gandalf'},
  };

  render() {
    const { usuario } = this.state;
    return (
      <HomeContext.Provider>
        <PaginaUsuario
          value={{ usuario: usuario }}
        />
      </HomeContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

const PaginaUsuario = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Titulo>Página do usuário</Titulo>
      <NomeUsuario/>
    </div>
  );
};

const NomeUsuario = ({ usuario }) => {
  return (
    <HomeContext.Consumer>
    {({ usuario }) => (
      <p>Usuario: {usuario.nome}</p>
    )}
    </HomeContext.Consumer>
  );
};
```

Se for seguir o caminho do `Render props`, ficaria assim o nosso exemplo inicial:

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    usuario: { nome: 'Gandalf'},
  };

  render() {
    const { usuario } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <PaginaUsuario
          renderItem={usuario => (
            <NomeUsuario
              usuario={usuario}
            />
          )}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const PaginaUsuario = ({ renderItem }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Titulo>Página do usuário</Titulo>
      <div>
        {renderItem()}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const NomeUsuario = ({ usuario }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Usuario: {usuario.nome}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**É uma prática comum?**

É bem comum isso acontecer e deve ser evitada, porque os componetes acabam ficando muito acoplados, sem falar que começa a repetir código e fica fácil o aparecimento de bugs dessa maneira.

**Refs:**

[Render Props - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)

[How to avoid Prop-drilling in React](https://medium.com/@jeromefranco/how-to-avoid-prop-drilling-in-react-7e3a9f3c8674)

[Context API - React](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: Muito bem explicado!

Comment: Dessa forma, para casos simples, isto é, como no exemplo, a melhor solução é usar Context API?