# Compartilhar um Hook de um componente para outro

Tags: react, react-hooks

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, tenho um componente no React chamado NavBar.jsx e gostaria que o **titulo** no NavBar alterasse assim que outro componente fosse aberto.

Por exemplo, quando abrir a tela de cadastro de cliente, alterar o titulo para "Cadastro de Clientes".

Usei o um HOOK do useState para criar o titulo.

Porém ao abrir outro componente queria alterar o state do titulo para um outro titulo assim que ele fosse renderizado, para isso tento chamar com useEffect, mas não funciona e da um erro.

"Attempted import error: 'setTitulo' is not exported from '../components/NavBar' (imported as 'NavBar')."

NavBar.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Nav, Navbar, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap'

const NavBar = (props) => {

const [titulo, setTitulo] = useState("Controle Diário")

return (
<Navbar className="shadow-lg mb-5 bg-secondary " variant="light">
    <Navbar.Brand href="/">
        <img
            src={logo}
            
            height="40"
            className="d-inline-flex align-top"
            alt="Logo"
        />
    </Navbar.Brand>
    <Nav className="mr-auto">
        <Nav.Link href="#">Controle Diário</Nav.Link>
        <NavDropdown title="Cadastro" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
            <NavDropdown.Item href="/clientes">Clientes</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#">Motorista</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#">Notas Fiscais</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Divider />
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#">Outros</NavDropdown.Item>
        </NavDropdown>
    </Nav>
    <h4 className="mr-auto font-weight-bold">{titulo}</h4>
</Navbar>
)}

export default NavBar
```

MainCliente.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import * as NavBar from '../components/NavBar'

const MainClientes = (props) => {

// Esta e a linha que esta gerando o erro

useEffect(NavBar.setTitulo("Cadastro de Clientes"),[])

....
```

Answer (score 2):

Tem muitas maneiras de fazer isso. Tem uma pergunta similar na [comunidade em Ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451584/is-it-possible-to-share-states-between-components-using-the-usestate-hook-in-r) que pode ajudar.

Dessa forma não funciona basicamente porque você está tentando acessar uma variável dentro do escopo de outra função.

Uma coisa que é legal ressaltar é que não é muito legal manter estado fora dos componentes ou store, isso pode causar problemas de atualização do DOM. Tenho algumas sugestões de solução:

1. Manter o estado no componente acima tem uma técnica bem legal de estudar conhecida com [HOC](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) que basicamente consiste em manter a parte logica nos componentes pais.

Dessa forma  imagine ter dois componentes filhos quer que eles compartilhem um estado para isso é só manter o estado no pai desta forma:

```js
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

function ChildA(prop) {
  return (
    <section>
      <button 
        onClick={
          () => prop.alterar('alterado atraves do A')
        }>
        Alterar atravez do A
      </button>
      Valor no A: { prop.valor }
    </section>
  )
}

function ChildB(prop) {
  return (
    <section>
      <button 
        onClick={
          ()=> prop.alterar('alterado atraves do B')
        }>
        Alterar atravez do B
      </button>
      Valor no B: { prop.valor }
    </section>
  )
}

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState('inicial');
  
  return (
    <div>
      <ChildA valor={state} alterar={setState} />
      <ChildB valor={state} alterar={setState} />
    </div>
   )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

2. Guarda isso em uma store como [redux](https://redux.js.org/) assim você tem a flexibilidade de acessar e alterar isso de qualquer lugar, o código fica meio complexo mas se estiver criando uma aplicação mais robusta é um bom caminho.

```js
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const ALTERAR = 'ALTERAR';

// ESSA SERIA SUA STORE
const reducer = (state = 'inicial', action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    
    case ALTERAR:
      return action.valor;
      
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const store = Redux.createStore(reducer);

const Provider = ReactRedux.Provider;
const connect = ReactRedux.connect;

// AQUI VOCE MAPEIA OS ESTADOS QUE O COMPONENTE IRA USAR PARA EVITAR RENDERIZAÇÕES DESNECESSARIAS
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { valor: state };
};

// AQUI VOCE MAPEIA OS REDUCERS QUE DESEJA USAR COMO PROP
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    alterar: (valor) => {
      dispatch({ type: ALTERAR, valor })
    }
  }
};

function ChildA(prop) {
  return (
    <section>
      <button 
        onClick={
          () => prop.alterar('alterado atraves do A')
        }>
        Alterar atravez do A
      </button>
      Valor no A: {prop.valor}
    </section>
  )
}

const ChildAConectado = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ChildA);

function ChildB(prop) {
  return (
    <section>
      <button 
        onClick={
          ()=> prop.alterar('alterado atraves do B')
        }>
        Alterar atravez do B
      </button>
      Valor no B: {prop.valor}
    </section>
  )
}

const ChildBConectado = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ChildB);


function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <main>
        <ChildAConectado />
        <ChildBConectado />
      </main>
    </Provider>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.0/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/5.0.7/react-redux.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

3. Você pode usar um lib específica para isso elas não são muito famosas por não serem oficiais mas cumprem oque prometem abaixo algumas delas:

   - [hooksy](https://github.com/pie6k/hooksy)
   - [use-between](https://github.com/betula/use-between#readme)

Comment: Obrigado pelo conteúdo em sua resposta, vou estudar com calma essas saídas possíveis para decidir qual utilizar.

Answer (score 1):

Dá uma checada na resposta desse post [O que é “Prop drilling”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/424783/163579) para uma explicação mais completa, nele também há alguns exemplos das três alternativas citadas abaixo.

> Há três alternativas:
>
> - **Redux**, mas é usado em casos específicos e quando realmente necessário, experiência própria, não use Redux se você não precisa
>   realmente.
> - **Context API** e **Render props**, o próprio React oferece ferramentas para lidar com isso.

Comment: Obrigado, dei uma olha no tópico, das opções que tem, vou tentar inicialmente o Render props, já achei bastante conteúdo sobre. Vou entender melhor e aplicar para ver como fica.